# Show that $1373653$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

How can I show that $n = 1373653$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $3$? I found this question as an exercise in a book I'm currently reading (which unfortunately doesnt provide a solution to this problem).
My attempt:
Using Miller's test to the base $3$, I have to show that $3^{343413} = 3^{7*23*27*79} \equiv 1$ (mod $829$) and (mod $1657$). I want to solve this question using my calculator as little as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the definition of a strong probable pseudoprime to some base (here $3$) ? You have to show two things : $(1)$ The given number satisfies this definition $(2)$ The given number is composite. If you know the factorization, you can use the chinese remainder theorem wo work with smaller numbers.

Comment: To reduce the exponent, you can use Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: If this is a homework-ish problem that really has a clever solution, then the fact that $1657= 2\cdot 829 -1$ surely matters?  (The opposite of a Germaine prime.)

Comment: Or you can use $a^{b\cdot x}=(a^b)^c$ repeatedly ... $3^7=81\cdot 27$ etc.